# Can't resolve 'react-dom' in '/path/node_modules/gatsby-react-router-scroll' when running "gatsby-develop"

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-dom

**Update**

It turns out that removing `gatsby-plugin-preact` from my `gatsby-config.js` fixes the issue. I don't know why though and I'd like to use preact

[Here is the project on Github](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/gatsby-plugin-preact-cant-resolve-react-dom)

---

I started the project with:

`gatsby new gatsby-starter-default https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default`

I run `gatsby develop` and get

```
 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Generating SSR bundle failed

Can't resolve 'react-dom' in '/path/node_modules/gatsby-react-router-scroll'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'react-dom' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

File: node_modules/gatsby-react-router-scroll/scroll-container.js

not finished Generating image thumbnails - 7.221s
```

I've already tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` `npm update` `npm i react-dom` `npm i react-router-dom` and this hasn't changed anything

---

**package.json**

```js
    {
      "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
      "private": true,
      "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
      "dependencies": {
        "gatsby": "^2.24.50",
        "gatsby-image": "^2.4.16",
        "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.24",
        "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.3.13",
        "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.25",
        "gatsby-plugin-preact": "^4.0.9",
        "gatsby-plugin-purgecss": "^5.0.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.10",
        "gatsby-plugin-root-import": "^2.0.5",
        "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.12",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.28",
        "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.4.12",
        "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^2.4.18",
        "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.26",
        "gatsby-transformer-json": "^2.4.11",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.13",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scroll": "^1.8.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "prettier": "2.1.0"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "gatsby"
      ],
      "license": "0BSD",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "gatsby build",
        "develop": "gatsby develop",
        "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
        "start": "npm run develop",
        "serve": "gatsby serve",
        "clean": "gatsby clean",
        "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
      },
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
      }
    }
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```js
const path = require(`path`)

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Title`,
    description: `Description.`,
    author: `Autho name`,
    themeColor: "#d2f5fb",
    siteUrl: "https://example.ca",
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `data`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data`
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/assets/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-root-import',
      options: {
        "components": path.join(__dirname, "src/components"),
        "styles": path.join(__dirname, "src/assets/styles"),
        "interfaces": path.join(__dirname, "src/interfaces"),
        "data": path.join(__dirname, 'src/data'),
        "pages": path.join(__dirname, 'src/pages')
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
    `gatsby-plugin-preact`,
    { 
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-purgecss`,
      options: {
        // printRejected: true, // Print removed selectors and processed file names
        purgeOnly: ['src/assets/styles', 'src/components','node_modules/'],
        ignore: ['node_modules/'],
        whitelist: [],
        whitelistPatterns: []
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: What was the command you used to setup the project (including url)?

Comment: @apena `gatsby new gatsby-starter-default https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default`

Comment: I ran the starter no problem just now. Perhaps its your version of node. What does `node -v` output?

Comment: @apena That's what I used to start the project but I've done stuff since starting it, did you use my package.json

Comment: Yes I did, runs for me. What version of node are you running?

Comment: v14.4.0 and you ran `npm install` after editing the package.json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220650/discussion-between-apena-and-sam).

Comment: @apena I think I’ll just restart my project, I’m not that far in

Comment: @apena It turns out the problem is gone if I take `gatsby-plugin-preact` out of my `gatsby-config.js`. Do you know what that's about? I would like to use preact

Comment: Yeah as I mentioned in the chat I am thinking there is a child dependency that does not play well with node 14.x. Try running a LTS version of node.js (12.18.3). Runs for me on node 12.4.0

Comment: @apena Here is the project on github, removing `gatsby-plugin-preact` from gatsby-config.js fixes the project

Comment: @apena [Here's the project](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/gatsby-plugin-preact-cant-resolve-react-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this error when moving from Gatsby v1 to v2. There's an official upgrade guide available here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v1-to-v2/

The steps I had to do in my case were:

1. change from `gatsby-link` to `gatsby`
2. install `react` & `react-dom`

In your case that would probably updating to the latest version on `gatsby-plugin-preact`: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-preact/

Answer (score 0):

Try re-adding `gatsby-react-router-scroll`.

`npm install gatsby-react-router-scroll`

You might want to run a `gatsby clean` first.

Comment: Didn't help, sorry